# Nested aggregate error with SSRS subtotal and grand total

Tags: reporting-services, dataset, aggregate-functions

```
SQL Server 2012
Visual Studio 2010
Dataset being used is called Performance
Formulas
ACB = Average Capital Base
IRR = Internal Rate of return = Total Gain/ACB
Contribution = ACB/Sum(ACB)*IRR
```

I am trying to calculate Investment Contribution. 
Here is an example calculation.

```
Account Total Gain  ACB     IRR     Contribution
ABC     2,000.00    20,000  10%        6.67%
DEF     2,000.00    10,000  20%        6.67%
total   4,000.00    30,000  13.33%     13.33%
```

Total IRR and Total Contribution always are equal

Note that contribution is the individual row ACB multiplied by the sum of ACB's then multiplied by the individual row IRR.

I have the following Report. My problem is I cannot get the subtotalling and totalling to work due to nested aggregates. I'm also not sure how to target the correct data scope.
[image: report]

IRR and IRR subtotal expressions (working)

```
=Fields!TotalGain.Value/Fields!ACB.Value
=Sum(Fields!TotalGain.Value)/Sum(Fields!ACB.Value)
```

[image: report]

Trying to get the Contribution calculation to work (comes up with the wrong number)

```
=Fields!ACB.Value/Sum(Fields!ACB.Value, "Performance")*Fields!IRR.Value
```

[image: report]

Trying to get the subtotal and total of contribution (in spite of the number being wrong)

```
=sum(Fields!ACB.Value/Sum(Fields!ACB.Value, "Performance")*Fields!IRR.Value)
```

[image: report]

I get this error
[image: report]

```
Error   3   [rsInvalidNestedDataSetAggregate] The Value expression for the text box ‘Textbox29’ has a nested aggregate that specifies a dataset scope.  Inner aggregates cannot specify a dataset scope.    F:\Automater\SSRS\Reports_2012\PerformanceSample2.rdl   0   0
```

I realize the error is related to trying to sum an already summed value but that is what the calculation calls for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your description above, it seems like you're working out **Contribution** to the **Classification** level, e.g. *Equities*, *Fixed Income*.

As such, when working out the total **ACB** for detail rows you need to work out the total in that particular **Classification** Scope.

Consider some simplified data:

[image]

I've called this DataSet **Performance** and have constructed a report based on it:

[image]

For the row level **Contribution** I used the expression:

```
=Fields!ACB.Value / Sum(Fields!ACB.Value, "Classification")
  * (Fields!TotalGain.Value / Fields!ACB.Value)
```

Here the Scope of the `SUM` expression is the group level.

For the sub total I used the expression:

```
=Sum(Fields!ACB.Value) / Sum(Fields!ACB.Value, "Classification")
  * (Sum(Fields!TotalGain.Value) / Sum(Fields!ACB.Value))
```

To me, these two expressions seem to give the expected results:

[image]

You'll note that since in the group level expression `Sum(Fields!ACB.Value)` is the equivalent of `Sum(Fields!ACB.Value, "Classification")`, this can actually be simplified to `Sum(Fields!TotalGain.Value) / Sum(Fields!ACB.Value)`, i.e. the IRR, which is what we expect, too.

If you need to work out **Contribution** to the total of *all* **Classifications**, i.e. a Grand Total, you'd have to change `"Classification"` to `"Performance"` in the above expressions.

Hopefully this helps you get your desired results.

Comment: Thank you. I have posted a reply below.

Answer (score 0):

Ian Preston,

Your answer set me on the right path and comes very close to getting me to the total. Solution. Therefore I've marked it as correct. However I wanted to add some additional feedback. You were correct I needed to specify rows by the row level scope which can be toggled for different classification levels and which is called **ClassificationMemberName**

Here is my row level formula for contribution

```
=Fields!ACB.Value/Sum(Fields!ACB.Value, "ClassificationMemberName")
* (Fields!TotalGain.Value/ fields!ACB.Value)
```

For some reason for the subtotal I need to multiply the value by 2 to get the correct result? However this only works for the classification at the asset level. If I classy by the total portfolio the value is doubled.

```
=sum(Fields!ACB.Value, "ClassificationMemberName")/
Sum(Fields!ACB.Value, "Performance")
*
sum(Fields!TotalGain.Value, "ClassificationMemberName")/
 sum(fields!ACB.Value, "ClassificationMemberName")*2
```

I attached the rdl if you'd like to see what I mean. I greatly appreciate your effort.

Here is the rdl

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/29851290/PerformanceSample2.rdl

Comment: Cool, thanks for the update - it's nice to see it helped! Not sure about the multiplier; it really depends on the combination of the underlying data and the report grouping. All I can suggest if you want to troubleshoot further is to add debug columns that show all the interim calculations, i.e. `Sum(Fields!ACB.Value, "Performance")` and try and see if one or more of these look incorrect and hence are affecting the overall value, then updating accordingly.